# Do we have c99 subflags

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, c99

Are there sub-options provided for -std=c99, so that i can pass those sub-options and get away from passing -std=c99?

For example:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would to compile this code with gcc by passing any sub-options.

$ gcc -sub-option-for-c99 a.c

Thanks

Edit: I want to pick just a single feature from C99, while keeping the rest of the compiler in C89 (or some other) mode.

Comment: What is a sub-option?

Comment: I don't understand at all - what's a sub-option for for `-std=c99`? And why do you want to get away from passing `-std=c99` (maybe you want to use `std=gnu99`?)

Comment: @Prof.Falken a minimal version of c99 which addresses the particular construct provided by c99.

Comment: So you want to pick just a single feature from C99, while keeping the rest of the compiler in C89 (or some other) mode?

Comment: @Prof.Falken yes exactly .

Comment: (Unfortunately, I suspect the answer to the question is "no". But interesting question, +1.)

Comment: C99 didn't have much provision for sub-setting the functionality (essentially no sub-setting).  C11 does have some provision for that.  However, the details of what is implemented tends to be controlled by the implementation, rather than something the programmer can change other than by an overall switch such as `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`.  That's a long-winded way of saying "**No**".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok got it. Thanks . May be you can post this as an answer so that i can accept it .

Comment: Your wish is my command.  Temporarily, anyway...

Comment: This strikes me as being somewhat unwise. How tightly do you want your code to be tied to a specific compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99 didn't have much provision for sub-setting the functionality (essentially no sub-setting). C11 does have some provision for that. However, the details of what is implemented tends to be controlled by the implementation, rather than something the programmer can change other than by an overall switch such as `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`. That's a long-winded way of saying "**No**".

Example of sub-setting in C11: Annex K (previously TR 24731-1) Bounds-Checking Interfaces.

A program can indicate that it wants to use the facilities by defining `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`, but that won't help you if the implementation does not itself define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`.

A more complete list of sub-setting from ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (with Corr.1 applied to the value of `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`):

> #### 6.10.8.3 Conditional feature macros
>
> ¶1 The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:
>
> - `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to
>     the specifications in annex L (Analyzability).
> - `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to the
>     specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).
> - `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate
>     adherence to the specifications in annex G (IEC 60559 compatible complex
>     arithmetic).
> - `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` The integer constant 201112L, intended to indicate support
>     for the extensions defined in annex K (Bounds-checking interfaces).<sup>179)</sup>
> - `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the
>     implementation does not support atomic types (including the `_Atomic`
>     type qualifier) and the `<stdatomic.h>` header.
> - `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the
>     implementation does not support complex types or the 
>     header.
> - `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the
>     implementation does not support the `<threads.h>` header.
> - `__STDC_NO_VLA__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the
>     implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably
>     modified types.
>
> ¶2 An implementation that defines `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` shall not define
>   `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__`.
>
> <sup>179)</sup> The intention is that this will remain an integer constant of type `long int` that is increased with
>   each revision of this International Standard.

See also section **6.10.8 Predefined macro names** generally for related information.

Note that these macros are defined or not defined by the implementation depending on what it does or does not support.  It won't make any difference if you try to set them yourself; they are intended for the implementation to communicate with you, not vice versa.

---

#### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.10.8 Predefined macro names

> ¶2 The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:
>
> - `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to the
>     specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).
> - `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate
>     adherence to the specifications in informative annex G (IEC 60559
>     compatible complex arithmetic).
> - `__STDC_ISO_10646__` An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example,
>     199712L), intended to indicate that values of type wchar_t are the
>     coded representations of the characters defined by ISO/IEC 10646, along
>     with all amendments and technical corrigenda as of the specified year and
>     month.
>
> ¶3 The values of the predefined macros (except for `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`) remain
>   constant throughout the translation unit.
>
> ¶4 None of these macro names, nor the identifier defined, shall be the subject of a
>   `#define` or a `#undef` preprocessing directive. Any other predefined macro names
>   shall begin with a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter or a second
>   underscore.
>
> ¶5 The implementation shall not predefine the macro `__cplusplus`, nor shall it define it
>   in any standard header.

Section 6.10.8 and its sub-sections are similar in ISO/IEC 9899:2011, but the set of macros discussed is more extensive.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there sub-options provided for -std=c99, so that i can pass those sub-options and get away from passing -std=c99

Nopes! gcc doesn't provide any such provision. Pass -std=c99 and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing so, it is usually a task for the preprocessor

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
#else
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
#endif
```

although in this case it seems a bit stupid.

Comment: You probably need to do something like `#if defined __STDC_VERSION__ &&  __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L`.

Comment: modifying the code might not be a good idea because there can be many c99 features in different files.

Comment: @Lundin: not really unless you think you're going to have to support a pre-C89 (yes, eighty-nine) compiler.  In C89 and above, any symbol that has not been expanded when a `#if` condition is processed is treated as a 0.  Of course, pre-C89 compilers didn't usually support `defined` as an operator either, so you'd be in trouble even so.  So, if `__STDC_VERSION__` is not defined, the compiler will treat it as 0 and 0 is less than 199901L (if it understands the proposed `#if defined ...` line at all).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In my experience, many pre-C99 compilers don't support STDC_VERSION. But you are right about the pre-processor translating it to 0 if it isn't defined, so maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can certainly find a lot of code in system headers similar to what you show; I'm just not convinced that some of that is a hangover from the transition period from 'before C89' to 'after C89'.  No great harm is done by being protective, but I'm not sure that great good is done either.

Answer (score 0):

What about this `-std=` argument:

> ‘gnu89’ GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is
>   the default for C code.